# thread::join failed: Invalid argument for c++20 std::jthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I'm using `c++20`'s `std::jthread` (I'm actually using `apple-clang 14.0` so I'm relying on [Nicolai Josuttis' implementation](https://github.com/josuttis/jthread)).

In the program below I'm unable to *join* the default-constructed `std::jthread thread` with a `thread.join()` at the end of `do_stuff()` and the program fails with the following output:

```
Starting thread...
Max attempts exceeded.
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: thread::join failed: Invalid argument
```

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <thread>

class ThreadedProcessor {

private:
    int attempt{0};
    const int max_attempts = 1;
    std::stop_source ssource;
    std::jthread thread;

    void do_stuff() {
        while (attempt < max_attempts) {
            ++attempt;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }
        fmt::print("Max attempts exceeded.\n");
        ssource.request_stop();
        thread.join();
    }

    void start() { // was previously called process()
        thread = std::jthread([&, stoken = ssource.get_token()]() {
            fmt::print("Starting thread...\n");
            while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
                do_stuff();
            }
            if (stoken.stop_requested()) {
                fmt::print("Stop requested. Stopping thread.\n");
            }
        });
    }

public:

    ThreadedProcessor() {
        process();
    }
};

int main() {
    auto tp = ThreadedProcessor();
}
```

How does one stop the thread properly in this case?

Comment: It's not allowed to join a thread in a thread itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. Would having the `thread.join()` statement as the conclusion of the constructor of `ThreadProcessor` be appropriate?

Comment: IDK what you are implementing. If you place join() in the constructor, you actually discard the thread advantage. I would not use join() at all.

Comment: Thanks again @273K . That makes sense, the `join()` is counterproductive since I'd like to accomplish other concurrent processes after `process()` as well.

Comment: IMO, a better name for your `process()` method would be `start()`. It doesn't process anything. All it does is start a thread, and then immediately return. A better name for your `do_stuff()` method would be `process()`. That's where all of the processing actually happens. IMO, a better name for your `ThreadProcessor` class would be `ThreadedProcessor`. It doesn't process threads, it _uses_ a thread to do its processing. (Or, you could call it `FoobarProcessor` if "foobars" are the things that it processes.)

Comment: Great points @Solomon Slow, I'll update my code accordingly.